# How to install Bluetooth on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, windows-server-2008-r2, service-pack

I noticed that the release notes for service pack 1 for Windows Server 2008 R2 says that it enables Bluetooth support.

I've apply the upgrade but I could not figure out how to get my Bluetooth devices to work. Do you still need to copy the Windows 7 drivers like the pre-SP1 blogs and articles say?

This is on a Dell Precision M4500 and Dell Precision T3500 with a Bluetooth dongle attached.